# Why am I receiving empty objects from post requests using Express?

Tags: node.js, express, post

With this code I only get back empty objects using Postman.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const product = {
    name: req.name,
    price: req.price,
  };
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Handling POST requests to /products',
    createdProduct: product
  });
});
```

Comment: `req.name` is undefined, you can access the body with `req.body.name`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried that however, I get this error message: "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
    }

Comment: i've tried in local and it works. How are you testing this api? The `content-type: application/json` header is correctly set?

Comment: POST: localhost:4000, body tab, raw, JSON applications/json = {
 "name": "Some String",
 "price": 50.99
}

Comment: I haven't used the header tab as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear I was using req.body to begin with. However, I was unsure how to fix this issue. In an attempt to troubleshoot I removed the .body.

I now understand that I need the .body.

The issue was that I was declaring:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
```

after I declared my routs meaning body-parser would not work under my /products route as the route had not been established yet.